# The OP is not "unknown"!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, deleted-accounts

I was reading [this answer](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/4507/2777) on CogSci when I saw:

> [image]

The main site on the other hand, *does* seem to know who wrote it:

> [image]

I think the *same* information should be displayed on the app as well, even if it is just a user number.

<sub>My main concern here is that there should be *parity* between the information available on the site and the app.</sub>

Comment: That user is deleted and they just throw any blah into it to fill a space

Comment: @random *Unknown* doesnt make much sense though. At the very least, there should be parity between the app and main sites.

Comment: I suspect the API currently does not provide this information i.e. if user is deleted it will just return NULL or something like that. If I'm correct, they need to change the API first.

Comment: This is on version 0.1.31

Answer (score 4):

As of version 0.1.34 coming out later today the app will have parity for displaying deleted users with the website.